# Can't figure out where exception was thrown in source code using Xcode debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I get the message, 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1' after I run my code in xcode, which I believe is referring to the exception breakpoint, 'All Exceptions' I've added. The 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1' shows up highlighting in green the thread in my main file

```
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));
```

My debugger console only says, '(lldb)'. After running 'bt' (backtrace) in the console, this is what is returned:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1b2bb4, 0x015748b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x015748b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x01884fe1 CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 17
frame #2: 0x01234d9e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
frame #3: 0x011a11d7 Foundation`_NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
frame #4: 0x011a0731 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
frame #5: 0x01202b0a Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
frame #6: 0x004eb1f4 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
frame #7: 0x015867de libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
frame #8: 0x017f076a CoreFoundation`-[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
frame #9: 0x004e9d4d UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
frame #10: 0x003526f5 UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
frame #11: 0x00352e9d UIKit`-[UIViewController loadView] + 302
frame #12: 0x003530d3 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
frame #13: 0x003535d9 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 35
frame #14: 0x00273267 UIKit`-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
frame #15: 0x002735ef UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
frame #16: 0x0027386b UIKit`-[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
frame #17: 0x0027e3c8 UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
frame #18: 0x0022ebc0 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
frame #19: 0x00233667 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
frame #20: 0x00247f92 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
frame #21: 0x00248555 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
frame #22: 0x00235250 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
frame #23: 0x037eaf02 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 776
frame #24: 0x037eaa0d GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
frame #25: 0x01770ca5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
frame #26: 0x017709db CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
frame #27: 0x0179b68c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2156
frame #28: 0x0179a9d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
frame #29: 0x0179a7eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #30: 0x00232d9c UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 840
frame #31: 0x00234f9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
* frame #32: 0x0000509d Matchismo`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffedd8) + 141 at main.m:16
```

I'm not entirely sure how to decipher this. From the guides I've been followed, they say that after including the 'All Exceptions' breakpoint, the thrown exception should be outlined in my source code. If someone could help guide about how to figure out the source of my crash, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Not all exceptions can be easily traced back to the error in your code. Read the first few lines of the stack trace, it looks like your problem is with Key Value Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the stack trace, the problem occurs when your view controller attempts to load a nib file.

```
frame #10: 0x003526f5 UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
```

The problem appears to be that the unarchiver is unable to set an outlet configured in the nib file.

```
frame #6: 0x004eb1f4 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
```

To get precise details about the exception, press the debugger's continue button (or type **continue**, or just **c** for short, in the console). You may need to do this twice to get all the information.

The exception message should provide you the exact name of the outlet. Perhaps you renamed or deleted a property after you had already set the outlet in Interface Builder. If you inspect the view controller in IB, you should see a yellow warning flag next to any stale outlets. Just click the x to delete.

The reason the debugger appears to stop in `main` rather than somewhere else is because the exception wasn't thrown in your code, so there's no matching source line for it do display.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, after pressing continue twice the debugger told me the exact outlet that was not matched correctly.